# Can't recover Whatsapp messages on new phone from Bluestacks

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, bluestacks

I've tried all the possible methods of restoring Whatsapp messages from a backup - via Google Drive and via copying the Whatsapp folder manually from Bluestacks to the corresponding new phone's storage folder. However, each time Whatsapp failed to recover the messages. The new phone has a different number than the one which was used in Bluestacks, but according to the guide in the official Whatsapp site it shouldn't be problematic. During the attempt to restore I was connected to Wifi (tried 2 Wifi networks) and not to cellular communication.
I really hope someone can help solve my problem please

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change your whatsapp number in bluestacks and backup your messages to google drive. Then you have to install that number on mobile and follow the steps. Through that you can see a backup recovery option on whatsapp. Give your gmail and download the backup to mobile. Enjoy as like in bluestacks android emulator.